# CodeDOM for creating classes from existing entity class

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

I used `CodeDOM` to generate a class (entity class) from a given database table. I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tutorial and made my application. It's OK and working fine. By using codeDOM can I edit an existing entity class and regenerate it against the table it's based on ? I searched for it but no luck. If so, can you point me to the direction. Or if not, How can I regenerate my existing class modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **CodeDom** you can generate a code for a class at runtime, but you can't modify an existing class. The only way is to regenerate it from scratch based upon your table, and I think is the approach you can use in your case.